# Can't override Linear Gradient in Tailwind?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Just jumped into Tailwind, all was great until this happened - I set my button to have a linear background gradient but also set a :hover to change its background, like this:

```
className="w-1/4 h-2/3 bg-gradient-to-b from-indigo-50 to-indigo-200 self-center
         rounded-lg text-indigo-800 text-4xl font-bold focus:outline-none hover:bg-white">
```

Issue is it seems the hover can't override the gradient, I searched and variants seemed to have been the solution but I add the variants like this and it still doesn't work:

```
variants: {
    extend: {      
      backgroundImage: ['hover', 'focus'],
    },
  },
```

Do I need to do something else after I declare the variants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bg-gradient` uses background-image not background-color. I suggest using from and to on hover state to white `hover:from-white hover:to-white`. See a [working demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/wiq0EztFhO).

```
<button class="w-1/4 h-2/3 bg-gradient-to-b from-indigo-50 to-indigo-200 self-center rounded-lg text-indigo-800 text-4xl font-bold focus:outline-none hover:from-white hover:to-white">
  Button
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
hover:bg-none
```

It's because bg-gradient adds background image property which is different than background color.